# Sparse random graph property

Tags: probability, random-graphs

I'm taking a course which follows the book:
High-Dimensional Probability by Roman Vershynin.

There is an exercise (2.4.4) in the book which I have trouble with:
Consider a random graph $G \sim G(n,p)$ with expected degrees $d=o(\log n)$. Show that with high probability (say 0.9), $G$ has a vertex with degree $10d$.

To solve this I want to take a subset of vertices $V' \subset V$ s.t. each two vertices in $V'$ are not neighbors in the graph, so their degrees are independent. Then use Poisson approximation.
But I think that this way the expected degree of the vertices in this group is no longer $d$, and I cant figure out what can I say about $|V'|$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Self answering for future reference.

We've solved it by taking $V' \subset V$ randomly of size $n^\frac{1}{3}$,
Since $d=o(\log n)$, $p=o(\frac{\log n}{n})$.
The expected number of edges between vertices in $V'$ is bounded by $n^\frac{2}{3}*p=o(\frac{\log n}{n^\frac{1}{3}})$ so with high probability, there are no edges between vertices in $V'$, therefore their degrees are independent.
Now since the degree of each vertex is the sum of Bernoulli Random variables with small probability, we'll use Poisson approximation,

$P(\exists i\leq n \, | \, d'_i = 10d) = 1 - P(\forall i\leq n \, | \, d'_i \neq 10d) = 1 - P(d'_i \neq 10d)^n = 1 - (1 - P(d'_i = 10d))^n$

$P(d'_i = 10d) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi 10d}}e^{-d}\frac{ed}{10d}^{10d} \geq ... \geq n^{-c}$
(by using $d \leq C_1\log n$, Thanks [Jiayao](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3133921/sparse-random-graph-property/3138089#comment6787580_3138089))
Which c is a constant that depends on $C_1$, which can be small as we like (since it's small o).

Now,
$1 - (1 - P(d'_i = 10d))^n \geq 1 - (1 - n^{-c})^n \geq 1 - e^{-n^{\frac{1}{3}}/n^c} = 1 - e^{-n^{\frac{1}{3}-c}}$
Now we can choose c as we like to get the desired lower bound on the probability.

Comment: Your answer works fine, but I want to mention that we don't *need* to find an independent set $V'$. You can choose any $V'$ of reasonable size and simply say that for every $v \in V'$, the number of neighbors $v$ has outside $V'$ is binomial, and these binomial variables are independent. Then argue that some $v \in V'$ has at least $10d$ neighbors outside $V'$, and therefore has degree at least $10d$.

Comment: The question asks one with exactly 10d, I don't know how much it'll affect your answer, but it is interesting to look at it that way as well!

Comment: Exactly $10d$? Huh. Well, we could first look at the degrees inside $V'$, and then that sets a target (which is at most $10d$) for the number of neighbors we want to find outside $V'$ for each vertex. So it still works out.

Comment: Ok I understand, so it's another option, thanks!

Comment: I am a bit confused - since $d=o(\log n)$, one should expect $d < c \log n$ for some $c$ instead of $d \ge C_1 \log n$. Did I miss anything?

Comment: $d=o(\log n)$ means that $d$ is asymptotically smaller than $c \log n$ for every c.

Comment: Wait, I see what you mean, I'll check it out again

Comment: I think I messed up with the greater than, and meant to write smaller than. I'll check it again and update if needed.

Comment: Thanks! Some detailed steps for future reference: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi 10 d}} \mathrm{e} ^ {-d} \left(\frac{\mathrm{e}d}{10d}\right)^{10d}$ $\sim$ $\exp \{-(10\log 10 - 9) d -\frac{1}{2} \log d\}$ $<$ $\exp \{-C_1 (10\log 10 - 9) \log n - \frac{1}{2} \log C_1 \log n\}$ $\sim$ $n^{-c_1} (\log n)^{-c_2} = o(n^{-c})$ for some $c$.
Also wish to ask in the last step, why $(1-n^{-c})^n \le \mathrm{e}^{-n^{1/3-c}}$, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure the application of the Poisson approximation is totally precise in the answer as written. $d_i'$ is a binomial-$(n-1,p)$ random variable which limits to a Poisson with parameter $d$ in the limit. Thus, for $Z$ a Poisson r.v. with param $d$, $P(d_i' = 10d) = P(Z = 10d) + o(1)$ by the Poisson limit theorem. Then we use Poisson approximation $P(Z = 10d) = ((2\pi\cdot 10d)^{-1/2}e^{-d}(ed/10d)^{10d})(1+o(1))$. I don't believe the $o(1)$ terms end up making a difference, but I don't believe this answer is fully correct as written without them. Happy to be proven wrong if I'm wrong